# 3D Bulk Modelling tools in GIS

Tags: 3d, software-recommendations

I work in an Architectural practice concentrating on large scale urban planning and Urban Design Schemes.

Our current software is not really geared for this sort of work.

We need to be able to accurately plot building block models onto accurate cadastral information.

Is there any type of software that would allow us to do this sort of work?

Answer (score 2):

There are many solutions to this, and your pick would depend on many factors, like your budget, compability with your existing systems/formats and required functionality. I'll give a few pointers:

For a simple and relatively affordable solution, take a look at SketchUp from Trimble. If this is not up for the job, there are two directions:

From the GIS world we have solutions like ESRI's CityEngine that ties he 3D into any existing GIS systems and formats that would be worth a look.

The CAD world have solutions based on CAD formats and Building information models (BIM) that can be worth a check, like Autodesk's AutoCAD Map 3D/Civil 3D, as seen e.g. in [this example](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/blog/2014/06/how-to-create-models-of-towns-with-building-heights/) from Ordnance Survey in the UK.

There are many other solutions like these that I am not familiar with. A search for CityGML compatible software should give a few alternatives to check out...